# Reflection when types are known

Tags: .net, vb.net, design-patterns

Is it advisable to use Reflection to map Data Readers to objects?  I think the traditional way of doing it is as follows (without Reflection):

```
Public Class Person
    Public Function Make(ByVal objDR As dbDataReader) As PersonType
        Dim Person As New PersonType
        'Loop through dbDataReader and create PersonType
        Return Person
    End Function
End Class
```

You would have a Make function in every domain class e.g. Order, OrderItem etc.

I was thinking about doing something like this instead:

```
Public Class clsTypes
    Public Function Make(ByVal objDR As dbDataReader)
       'Use Reflection to map data reader to appropriate type
    End Function
End Class
```

OrderType, PersonType, OrderItemType etc inherit from clsType, so they can call clsType.Make e.g.

```
Dim p as new Person p.Make(objDR)
```

Once I have all the mapping code in one place I intend to introduce AutoMapper.  However, in the meantime, is it bad practice to use Reflection when you know what the types are at compile time? The reason for doing this is to reduce the amount of code, possibly at the expense of processing speed.

Comment: Have you looked at LINQ to SQL?

Comment: How would the code using the reflection know what type was appropriate based only on the data reader?  Does the data reader have a property that somehow specifies the type of data it is reading?

Comment: @Steven Doggart, the types all inherit from clsType i.e. clsType.Make is shared by all the types (PersonType, OrderType etc).  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw, I plan to use Entity Framework and Linq for future projects.  This is a legacy system.

Comment: Wouldn't all the code to actually call the data reader and populate the data structure be different for each type anyway?  How much of that code is actually common between each type?

Comment: Definitely at the expense of processing speed and I see no particular advantage in doing this. Less lines of code, but slower, more complex and fragile in a different way.

Comment: `Public Shared Function Make(Of T)(ByVal objDR As dbDataReader) As T` ?

Comment: @abhitalks, I would still have to use Reflection in your example, wouldn't I?

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson, thanks.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by: "fragile"? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977: generics. as your types are derived from a common class and assuming that they have all the properties returned by the datareader, reflection is not required.

Comment: @abhitalks, thanks.  Are you able to post an answer as this sounds like a good interim approach? By interim I mean between now and when I introduce Automapper.

Comment: @w0051977: there. added as an answer, although am not too sure if that is an answer :)

Comment: @w0051977. At the moment if you changed the table, you have to change the assignments in the Class when reading. If you went down the reflection route you'd be deriving the mapping from the column name, the property name or perhaps and attribute on the property. So still fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics by taking out this method from your type definition, something like this:

```
Public Shared Function Make(Of T)(ByVal objDR As dbDataReader) As T
```

*Important*: This is assuming that your types have all the properties corresponding to the dbDataReader.

*However*, if you need to loop thru the properties and pick up the relevant column, you will have to use reflection on that type and also will have to check the existence of that particular column in the dbDataReader.

In that case, you can have a utility function to check the existence in dbDataReader, something like this:

```
Public Shared Function IfExists(ByVal record As Common.DbDataRecord, ByVal columnName As String) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To record.FieldCount - 1
        If record.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Where you loop the dbDataReader and pass each DbDataRecord you pass the reflected property name as columnName.

I don't think reflection should be a bad practice in this case. Of course, there will be some performance penalty, but you gain code-reuse and DRY. Choice ultimately is yours.

And yes, get an ORM to get yourself out of all this.

**Update (based on comments)**:

I will illustrate it with an example. (Please note that these are just examples and are crude at best). As you said your classes inherit from a common type and the properties are known to you.

So your base class is this:

```
Public Class ClsType
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property Desc As String
End Class
```

And these classes inherit from `ClsType`:

```
Public Class Person
    Inherits ClsType
End Class

Public Class Order
    Inherits ClsType
End Class
```

So you create a `Utility` class (or your library code):

```
Public NotInheritable Class Utility
    Public Shared Function Make(Of T As {ClsType, New})(ByVal objDR As Common.DbDataReader) As List(Of T)
        Dim result = New List(Of T)
        For Each rec As Common.DbDataRecord In objDR
            Dim tmp As T = New T
            If IfExists(rec, "Id") AndAlso Not rec.IsDBNull(rec.GetOrdinal("Id")) Then tmp.Id = rec.GetString(rec.GetOrdinal("Id"))
            If IfExists(rec, "Desc") AndAlso Not rec.IsDBNull(rec.GetOrdinal("Desc")) Then tmp.Desc = rec.GetString(rec.GetOrdinal("Desc"))
            result.Add(tmp)
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function IfExists(ByVal record As Common.DbDataRecord, ByVal columnName As String) As Boolean
        For i As Integer = 0 To record.FieldCount - 1
            If record.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

Now, whenever you need to populate data from the datareader for any class (note that the type is known to you as per your question, and so are the properties), you just call this utility like this:

```
    Dim result As List(Of Person) = Nothing
    Dim objDR As Common.DbDataReader = Nothing
    result = Utility.Make(Of Person)(objDR)
```

***Note***:

This is based purely on assumption that the type(s) and their properties are known. In such a case, you can safely hard-code all the known properties. Of course, as @tony said, if you change the database, you will have to sync the classes yourself.

*If not*, then you have *no choice* but to use reflection on `T` in the `Make` method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Have you used this approach before? +1.

Comment: Yes and No. Yes, for the reflection i.e. the second part of my answer especially for reporting purposes when I have to populate different DTOs from all-purpose views. No, for the generic part. I prefer to keep separate data-layers for each domain entity.

Comment: I don't understand how the code in part 1 populates the object without Reflection.

Comment: @w0051977: i think i missed the constraint. `Make(Of T As New)`. Now you instantiate it inside the method and use properties: `Dim NewInstance As T = New T`, and then: `NewInstance.Property1 = X`... Am sorry, I am unable to remember everything off-the-hand :(

Comment: @w0051977: this will help you further: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379608(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Surely you would have to know the type(Of T) in order to initialise it with values from the datareader? i.e. in your last comment you say: NewInstance.Property1.

Comment: Not really. You are already calling that on a known type. Inside the function you just do a `dim obj = new T`

Comment: How would you map PersonID from the DataReader to PersonID in the PersonType? (this is just an example - likewise, how would you map OrderID in the DataReader to OrderID in the object.

Comment: Can you give me 8-10 hours. It's midnight here. Shall get back to u tomorrow morning.

Comment: @w0051977: there. i updated the answer to illustrate what i was trying to say. you are absolutely right, if you don't want to hard-code the known properties, or the properties are unknown, then you will have to use reflection anyway.

Comment: Do you think it is bad practice to use Reflection for this? Would you use it?

Comment: @w0051977: I personally don't think that it would a bad practice. What are those ORMs doing under-the-hood anyways? I think I said it in the first comment itself, that I do use reflection especially for reporting purposes when I have to fill up DTOs from SQL Server views.

Comment: Do you only use reflection if you do not know the type at runtime?

Comment: @w0051977: it all depends. using reflection on known types would save me at least one less place to change the code when database/domain model changes. so, when i use one big all-purpose view in SQL to fill-up different DTOs, i do use reflection so that i don't need to change my repository code whenever columns change. there is no one-size-fits-all scenario. how much performance you are ready to trade-off over maintenance and re-usability.... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Dapper? It's a mini-ORM that basically maps from a SQL query to a class.

You can have this:

`var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });`

and he automatically returns a Generic List of the class Dog, filled with the fields of the query. You only need to have the query fields with the same name in the class.

You can look  for more info at https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/